# Changed JaCoCo from offline to online, but still don't see coverage for classes in other modules

Tags: maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a largish Maven multi-module project build.  I'm starting with all of our tests using PowerMock, and using Jacoco 0.7.8 and offline instrumentation.

Despite the fact that these are called "unit tests", the tests for classes in one module do call significant code in other modules.  As a result, when we view the generated reports, we see the coverage for the classes in the same module as the test, but we don't see coverage for classes in other modules that were executed during the test.

My ASSUMPTION is that if I'm able to change this to use online instrumentation, the resulting coverage report would include the classes from other modules outside of the current module.

So, I set about fixing the one detail in our CUTs (class under test) that required the use of PowerMock instead of Mockito (that part was pretty simple).  I fixed this one by one in each test and corresponding CUT, but for now I've only made these changes in a single module in the larger build.  I verified that the tests work, and that I can see interactive coverage with EclEmma (another limitation of PowerMock).

The jacoco-maven-plugin is configured in the parent pom that is used by all of the child modules, to presently use offline instrumentation.  Eventually, I'm going to change the config in this parent pom to use online instrumentation, but I've decided to leave that there for now and override the config in each module that I've done the conversion in, so that that module uses online instrumentation.  I believe I've done that "properly", although I had to use a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440418/is-it-possible-to-override-executions-in-maven-pluginmanagement) to override the executions list in the child module (remember I'm going to be deleting these once all of them are converted).

When I run the build ("`clean install`"), I see it do "`prepare-agent`", printing the resulting "`argLine`" value, then later on surefire executes, then the "`report`" goal executes, printing the path to the `jacoco.exec` file, and I see that it says "`Analyzed bundle 'my-module-name' with 1 classes`".  That seems indicative of a problem.

As the build was now complete, I then opened the "`target/site/jacoco/index.html`" file in my browser, and I found that it only included coverage for the present module, and only the single class.

What was also curious is that I superficially inspected the generated "`jacoco.exec`" file.  I noticed that it was definitely larger than I was used to seeing from other modules still using offline instrumentation.  I don't have any way to interpret the format of the file, but I did try to simply "`cat`" the file, just to see what I can see.  I saw strings that represented class names in other modules that my tests are executing.

So, it seems like online instrumentation is at least recording data for classes in other modules, but the resulting report doesn't show that.

Is it possible to get this coverage?

The following is an excerpt from the "effective-pom" output:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-instrument</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>instrument</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-report</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>prepare-agent</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>@{argLine} -Xmx1024m</argLine>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <running-unit-test>true</running-unit-test>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>...\target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>@{argLine} -Xmx1024m</argLine>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
      </includes>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <running-unit-test>true</running-unit-test>
        <jacoco-agent.destfile>...\target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Notice that the executions used for offline instrumentation have phase "`none`", so they aren't used, and I'm also setting the "`jacoco-agent.destfile`" property, which is only used for offline instrumentation.

Answer (score 0):

[Goal `report`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html) performs analysis of **classes only in current module** and creates report containing only them, even if data was recorded for other classes. And [goal `report-aggregate`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html)

> coverage report from multiple projects within reactor

(see below for example)

Also coming back to PowerMockito - as was said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42305077/244993 it adds additional complexity, however:

`a/src/main/java/example/A.java`:

```
package example;

class A {
  // to be tested in module "a"
  void a() {
    System.out.println("A_a" + fun());
  }

  // to be tested in module "b"
  void b() {
    System.out.println("A_b" + fun());
  }

  // to be mocked by PowerMockito
  static String fun() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

`a/src/test/java/example/ATest.java`:

```
package example;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@PrepareForTest({A.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ATest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
    Mockito.when(A.fun()).thenReturn("fun");

    new A().a();
  }
}
```

`b/src/main/java/example/B.java`:

```
package example;

class B {
  // to be tested in module "b"
  void b() {
    System.out.println("B_b" + fun());
  }

  // to be mocked by PowerMockito
  static String fun() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

`b/src/test/java/example/BTest.java`:

```
package example;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@PrepareForTest({A.class, B.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class BTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
    Mockito.when(A.fun()).thenReturn("fun");

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(B.class);
    Mockito.when(B.fun()).thenReturn("fun");

    new A().b();
    new B().b();
  }
}
```

`a/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>a</artifactId>
</project>
```

`b/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>a</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <artifactId>b</artifactId>
</project>
```

`report/pom.xml` for aggregation of coverage across modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>report</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>a</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>b</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and finally most important part - `pom.xml` where happens all the magic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
    <powermock.version>1.6.6</powermock.version>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>a</module>
    <module>b</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>coverage</id>
      <modules>
        <module>report</module>
      </modules>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
          <classifier>runtime</classifier>
          <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>instrument</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>instrument</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <!--
                restore original classes before generation of report,
                but after packaging of JAR:
                -->
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

in such setup

```
mvn clean verify -Pcoverage
```

will generate

- `a/target/site/jacoco/index.html` containing coverage for classes in module `a` by tests in module `a`
- `b/target/site/jacoco/index.html` containing coverage for classes in module `b` by tests in module `b`
- `report/target/site/jacoco-aggregate/index.html` containing coverage for classes in modules `a` and `b` by tests in modules `a` and `b`

but produced JAR files contain instrumented classes, however

```
mvn package -DskiptTests -Dmaven.jar.forceCreation
```

will produce non-instrumented JARs.

This complexity not needed in case if you get rid of PowerMockito. In this case `coverage` profile in `pom.xml` can be simplified to:

```
<profile>
  <id>coverage</id>
  <modules>
    <module>report</module>
  </modules>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

and `mvn clean verify -Pcoverage` will generate same reports and JARs that do not require rebuilding.

Comment: What I really need to understand is, assuming all of the tests for a module are mockito, and using jacoco online instrumentation, how can the tests for a module show the coverage for classes outside of the module?  I assume that as I'm using the "merge" goal to produce a merged jacoco.exec file, my sonarqube output will have all of the coverage, but I'd like to be able to see that coverage in the generated jacoco report. Is there any way to get that?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr As of now there is no single word nor about "SonarQube" nor about "merge" in description of your question. As was already said [few](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42302786/jacoco-only-shows-coverage-for-classes-in-the-same-module/42305077#42305077) [times](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/bFJlLT0sROk/9riq_jz9BgAJ) - please make an effort to provide [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get an answer that precisely matches your case. BTW have you tried to execute "report-aggregate" on your merged file?

Comment: I didn't mention sonarqube because I don't have any problem with it. As far as I can tell, it's taking the data from the merged exec file, which has the data for classes outside of the calling module in each case. And yes, I also use report-aggregate, which I didn't mention in this posting because I was focusing on the build of each module, not the aggregation, but I also note that the report-aggregate output is also missing the coverage for the classes that are reached from outside of the module.  In each case, the coverage is "shallow".

Comment: @DavidM.Karr okay. To be able to help you - how to reproduce such behavior?

Comment: Dunno.  Guess I'll have to spend time trying to build a reproducible test case.  That will take a long time, and I don't even know if I'll be able to. It might have been useful if I could have turned on any diagnostics in jacoco that might provide clues. At this point, I can see that I get full coverage in EclEmma, and if the resulting build on the master branch shows full coverage in SonarQube, I may not be able to justify the time to build this reproducible test case.

Comment: I'm going to update the question with more info about how I'm doing the "merge" and "report-aggregate".

Comment: I'm going to post a separate question about my aggregation goals.

Comment: Actually, never mind.  It's clear to me now the report and report-aggregate goals will be useless to me, no offense. If there's no way to get anything more than "shallow" reported coverage, we'll just rely on running test suites with EclEmma and the overall SonarQube report, both of which provide deep coverage info.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr there is absolutely no difference betwee how Maven plugin, SonarQube and EclEmma generate reports from exec files - they call exact same APIs in JaCoCo, you have pure configuration issue

Comment: From what you said above: "Goal report performs analysis of classes only in current module and creates report containing only them, even if data was recorded for other classes". This is clear from what "report" generates. However, I can clearly see that EclEmma shows me coverage for classes in other modules.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr from what I said above: **report-aggregate** generates reports taking into account classes from other modules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136583/discussion-between-david-m-karr-and-godin).